# Exception insert record to SQL Server in C# by stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlexception, invalidoperationexception

I'm trying to insert a supplier to SQL Server but it always throws an exception on the line `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`. Really need some help!

[image]

Comment: You should show some code and the exception message for the community to be able to help you

Comment: Really need some of your code!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please copy and past code and error messages instead of posting images.

Comment: most of the folks you want to have help you will not deal with image only questions.  see the link above provided by @swe

Answer (score 5):

You never give the `command` object a connection, either do so in the `SqlCommand()` constructor or use `command.Connection = con;`

(An `SqlCommand` is disposable; you should create and use it within a `using () {}` construct to prevent resource leak)